# aframe gyroscope issue on some android devices

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have been using Aframe for a while now making small apps on it.

I have a Nubia N1 android 6.0 version which stopped orienting it horizontally but for vertical still works and there is less lag now.

**Other devices that are generating this issue are:**

It happens with some of the phones like:
Honor 6x (Android version 7.0)
Moto m droid 6.0

**Devices that are fine:**
Oppo A57 (droid 6.0.1)
One plus 5

I have been using aframe version 0.7.0..... I have slightly modified it, here is the link:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-trybucket/aframe-0.7.1.min.js

Comment: This a known Chrome regression. More info on: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug on Chrome m65 where the DeviceMotion API does not return rotationRate. It will be fixed in Chrome m66. In the meantime you can use A-Frame master branch. More details on this A-Frame issue: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3458

Comment: Where is source code of A-Frame Master Branch? Please.

Comment: A build from the master branch can be found here: https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-master.min.js

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Diego.