# Aframe, VR website, unable to turn left right using android phone

Tags: html, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I have been working on this VR website for my project for sometime. It used to be able to allow user to view left/right side of the virtual world by moving your phone to the left/right. However, just recently, it suddenly did not work for android phone. I have tested on iphone/ipad, still works as per normal.

But for some reason, i tried using note8 , s7 it doesnt work anymore. 
Would really appreciate if you can identify whats the problem, and how can I fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aframe gyroscope issue on some android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333063/aframe-gyroscope-issue-on-some-android-devices)

Comment: it seems you stumbled on the same bug as OP of the linked question, please check it out

Comment: Thanks for replying! yes, seems like similar problem, so how do I downgrade my mobile chrome version?  or will it be fixed after the next chrome update? 
Anyway, I managed to make it work on android phone, by going to the website using samsung internet built-in app. Thanks.

Comment: I've posted an anwser in case it won't be marked as a duplicate, if it solves your problem, feel free to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using firefox on android, or the built-in samsung internet app.

If everything works as expected, it means you've stumbled on a bug in the recent chrome build, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333063/aframe-gyroscope-issue-on-some-android-devices), which should be fixed in the next build.

Also using the latest a-frame master build should solve the issue for now.

Comment: Let me test it, can I have the link of the latest a-frame master build? Thank you.

Comment: @KeithOng sure, you can grab it from [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/tree/master/dist#a-frame-builds)