# Rotation on mobile

Tags: aframe

I am trying to find a way to rotate around my own axis on mobile with A-frame. Maybe I am asking something complete strange or it should work from default?
Using the default demo @ https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/ I expect that I can change my looking angle horizontally ( left right ) and Vertically ( up down). For me only top down works, and have to drag left and right with my finger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aframe, VR website, unable to turn left right using android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361993/aframe-vr-website-unable-to-turn-left-right-using-android-phone)

Comment: probably you've stumbled upon a bug described above, if not, then please provide more info about your phone