# Aframe - Mobile Chrome behavior

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, three.js, aframe, webvr

About a week ago I noticed a weird behaviour of A-Frame on Mobile Chrome that you can see in the videos below. You can't look left or right and looking up and down is slow. Funny thing is that everything works fine on Samsung's Internet browser.

Both videos show the [A-Frame's Hello World example](https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/) and are run on Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 7.0

Chrome Android 65.0.3325.109:
[A-Frame Helo World on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzmHD.gif) (gif)

Samsung Internet 6.4.10.5
[A-Frame Helo World on Samsung Internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b3Un.gif) (gif)

Any ideas why that might be happening?

Comment: You've probably stumbled upon a recent chrome bug, it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333063/aframe-gyroscope-issue-on-some-android-devices).

Comment: no problem, have fun with a-frame :)